# android - Force my app to use WiFi only

Tags: android, connection

I'm a PHP developer, but I'm now finishing Android App that different developer started.

One of the requirements is to make it possible to disallow mobile connection. For that I already created checkbox preference on settings page I got.

But I can't find correct way to globaly disallow my app to use mobile connection for data transactions. I don't need to disable connection, I just need to forbid my app to use it and use only WiFi. I got too much places, where connection is done and no time to refactor it.

TL;DR
I need to globally forbid my app to use mobile connection without disabling connection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just can say one thing is that Android allows to turn on/off WiFi manually only because of security.